# ImageView not replaced with other drawable

Tags: android, drawable, android-imageview

When taping on an `ImageView`, I want to replace it with other drawable depending on the previous drawable, with some researches I made this:

```
ImageView imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
imgview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
        assert(R.id.imageView1 == imageView.getId());
        Integer integer = (Integer) imageView.getTag();

        integer = integer == null ? 0 : integer;

        switch (integer) {
        case R.drawable.number1:

            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.number2);
            imageView.setTag(R.drawable.number2);
            break;

        case R.drawable.number2:
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.number3);
            imageView.setTag(R.drawable.number3);
            break;

        case R.drawable.number3:
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.number4);
            imageView.setTag(R.drawable.number4);
            break;
        default:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "exceeded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});

}
```

The problem is the app always calls to the `toast` message in `default`. It ingores all other treatments/verifications in `case` sections.

Any idea please to solve that problem?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is

You have written following statement

```
integer = integer == null ? 0 : integer;
```

So very first time control reached in click block that time tag will be null and above statement will make it 0.**But you are doing nothing to handle case 0**.

So in every case your tag will be 0 and it will cause default block execution.If you are setting tag as 0 then you must have switch case for 0.Otherwise it will always be 0 and default block keep on executing.

Your code snippet should look something like follow.

```
ImageView imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.number1);
imageView.setTag(R.drawable.number1);

imgview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
        assert(R.id.imageView1 == imageView.getId());
        Integer integer = (Integer) imageView.getTag();

        switch (integer) {
        case R.drawable.number1:

            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.number2);
            imageView.setTag(R.drawable.number2);
            break;

        case R.drawable.number2:
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.number3);
            imageView.setTag(R.drawable.number3);
            break;

        case R.drawable.number3:
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.number4);
            imageView.setTag(R.drawable.number4);
            break;
        default: 
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "exceeded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.number1);  <----You should reset it to number 1
            imageView.setTag(R.drawable.number1);
        }
    }
});

}
```

Comment: the problem is if i remove that line i will have a force close, i just read that i MUST put that line. And sincerly i don't have an idea of how solving it.

Comment: I tested other thing: It always triggers the default case even when i put a `1` in that line.

Comment: Excellent answer. Can you please explain that added two lines? And there is other problem, in the first state when the first drawable is displayed, i have to tap 2 times to pass to the other drawable. Any idea please?

Comment: And that line should not be deleted, otherwise i'll have a force close. `integer = integer == null ? 0: integer;`

Comment: @androniennn in case 3 you are setting tag as number4.so next time when you will be in switch case it will go to dafault.and this cycle will continue.thats why you need to reset it

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation, so that's why i have to tap 2 times to pass to the next drawable. First time, to override number 1, second tap to pass to the next drawable. That second tap is useless...

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't set a drawable id as the tag for the `ImageView` when you create it, like:

```
ImageView imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
imgview.setImageResource(R.drawable.number1);
// ...
```

and integer becomes `0`, avoiding all the `switch`'s cases. Test and see what is the value of integer(I would say it's `0`).

You can't set an integer as the tag in xml so the only option is to set it in code, thing that you probably didn't do(at least not in the code you posted).

Another approach:

```
        final int[] ids = {R.drawable.number1, R.drawable.number2, R.drawable.number3};     
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            int counter = 0;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (counter % 3 == 0) {
                    v.setBackgroundResource(ids[0]);
                } else if (counter % 3 == 1){
                    v.setBackgroundResource(ids[1]);
                } else if (counter % 3 == 2){
                    v.setBackgroundResource(ids[2]);
                }
                counter++;
            }
        });
```

Comment: You have reason, i just checked out and i always "give" a `0`. As Vipul Shah said the problem is from that line `integer = integer == null ? 0 : integer;`. But no idea of how solving it...

Comment: @androniennn I've edited my answer and added another approach to what you're trying to do. This is for the case when you want to cycle through those drawables.

Comment: Thank you dude, i will test that approach, it seems very simple comparing to mine. Thank you :)